# Is heap fragmentation a problem in bare-metal arm with g++?

Tags: c++, embedded-systems

I am converting a project from C to mixed C/C++. It is going quite nice, and the new features are really lightening the work.

The platform is an ARM SAM4, compiler is arm-none-eabi-g++. This is not a safety-related equipment, but still could be left running for months and is not supposed to restart sporadically.

The original C project has managed quite nicely to solve problems without a single `malloc` call, allocating statically all needed data. For example, arrays with unknown size are allocated to the maximum expected size.

Now I am considering can I get away with using `new`. For example, all STL containers hold their content in the heap. Just adding a new element to a `vector` can cause de-allocation of a whole region of the heap and allocation of another one.

Will there be fragmentation issues?

Related:

[What is memory fragmentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770457/what-is-memory-fragmentation)

Answer (score 5):

Working in a constrained memory environment (something that few of us do these days), it is entirely reasonable to use no heap allocation whatever. And C++ can work very nicely to make that possible.

Yes, the C++ collections for the most part do use the heap, because they are designed to grow without limit. Yes, it is almost impossible to ensure that the heap will never be fragmented, using the default allocator. I would not use it without a lot of prior thought.

This gives you two broad choices. Either stick to non-heap collections (which means std::array), or write your own allocator.

Wrapping existing arrays in std::array brings some benefits, but you will have to decide whether they are worth the effort.

A custom allocator can take advantage of your knowledge of how and when memory should be recovered. That might be by keeping free lists, or by periodic reset, or using pools, or some other strategy. It depends on how valuable the heap is to you.

Regardless, C++ has many other benefits. Perhaps the heap is just one step too far.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of telling if heap fragmentation will be a problem *in your application*. We can't tell, because heap fragmentation is the result of certain usage patterns of the memory (de-)allocator and you have not provided any info on that pattern.

In general, you can expect fragmentation issues if you constantly allocate and deallocate objects with varying sizes and varying lifetimes, such that it would be rare to be able to fit a new memory request into a slot that was recently released or that many memory allocations would leave an unusable small number of bytes unused between them. 
Such patterns can be very subtle and they also depend on the allocation strategy used by `new`/`delete`. Also note that leaked objects effectively get eternal lifetime as far as the memory management is concerned.

You can try to avoid fragmentation by setting up multiple allocators, so that you can allocate different types of objects from different pools. If all objects in a pool have close to the same size, then fragmentation won't be an issue.

Another option is to try to organize your allocations such that objects with a similar lifetime are allocated close together (in time). That also limits the chances of getting fragmentation, because the objects that are always there will be close together in one part of the heap and the more volatile objects will get allocated from a different part of the heap.

---

Growing a `std::vector<>` doesn't cause memory fragmentation, but it does have the nasty side effect that you effectively need double the normal amount of memory while growing the vector. This can be an issue if you only have a limited amount of RAM available.
To avoid this problem, you can use `std::vector<>::reserve()` to set the allocated memory close to the expected maximum.

Comment: Why would pushing an element to`vector` beyond it's capacity not cause fragmentation? Isn't it the same as freeing some memory and then allocating new chunk?

Comment: Do you know where can I get documentation on the specific implementation of my heap allocator. I am using `arm-none-eabi-g++ (GCC) 4.7.2`. All I could find was [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/)? And thirdly, would some defragmentation procedure be possible for an embedded system?

Comment: @Vorac: Pushing an element to a `vector` beyond its current capacity doesn't cause fragmentation because the memory left behind after the reallocation is typically large enough for several other allocations. But it could just be down to semantics.

Comment: @Vorac: That documentation is most likely found in the (developer) documentation or source code comments of the `libstdc++` that you are using. A defragmentation is typically not possible in a C++ program, because you need a record of all live pointers in your system to adjust them to the moved location of what they point to and such a record is not kept.

Answer (score 0):

If the C code is written in such a way that there are no fragmentation issues then it's 100% possible to write similar code in C++.

You could use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

I'll add that it seems to me that you're trying to solve a problem that isn't there.